# Why is Thread detecting two objects even though one was created?

Tags: java, multithreading

```java
public class ThreadExample {

    public static ArrayList<ThreadExample> instances = new ArrayList<ThreadExample>();

    public ThreadExample() {
        instances.add(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadRead threadRead = new ThreadRead();
        ThreadCreate threadCreate = new ThreadCreate();
        threadCreate.start();
        threadRead.start();

    }

}

class ThreadRead extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(ThreadExample.instances.size());
    }
}

class ThreadCreate extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        ThreadExample.instances.add(new ThreadExample());
    }
}
```

The output of the code is "2"

The output I expected from the code was 1 or 0. Because if ThreadCreate reads ThreadRead at the same time while creating an object, I could expect "0" to come up because it will read before the construction of the object is completed. Or everything would go well and I would get the result "1". What is going on here that I don't know?

Thanks.

Comment: Getting 2 has little to do with multi-threading. Try doing everything in the same thread. `ThreadExample.instances.add(new ThreadExample());` and then `System.out.println(ThreadExample.instances.size());`. You'd get 2.

Comment: There's no thread safety here. The output is undefined (though it will be 0, 1, or 2).

Comment: What is `ThreadWrite`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you added twice.
You add a object.

```
ThreadExample.instances.add(new ThreadExample());
```

And you add again

```
instances.add(this);
```

Comment: Yes, I missed it. It has nothing to do with the thread.